# PHP How To Default Input Field

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, barcode

So I am programming a web based application to read from barcode scanner, and I noticed the barcode scanner scans, outputs value, and hits "Enter" key as macro. I can always make users click the input field, then scan, but I would like it so they can just scan, and it defaults the output into the input field and hit enter on its own in the field so they can just pull up info by just scanning an item. Is there a way to interpret if there are ANY keyboard input (they'll be integers input, since their barcodes around the store seems to be all numbers based) triggers the system to input the output from scanner into a field specified? Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: You need to set the focus of mouse cursor on that field by using javascript by default

Comment: Anything you do on the clientside must(should) be done in Javascript, such as "when the user does this I want to do that"  Use JS.  `Is there a way to interpret if there are ANY keyboard input`  In Javascript (with jquery) `$(selector).keyUp(function(event){ .... })` etc.

Comment: You should change the title and tags for your question to JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: A bit of a noob with javascript, would you happen to know an example of what that might look like in javascript?